# Moving Window in Matlab

Tags: matlab, window, pca

I'm looking to use Matlab to run through a set of data, 5446100 x 6 called xdata1. 
I'm looking it to plot the first 100 data points, and after this to run through each point individually. 
To start I have:

for i=1:100 
NOC1 = CPMD_PCA(xdata1(99+i,:);

How would I then get this to carry on continuously, other than writing out i=2:101, i=3:102 etc

Comment: What is it that you want to do - call `CPMD_PCA` on `xdata(2:101, :)`, then `xdata(3:102, :)` etc?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, call xdata(2:101,:) up to xdata(544600:5446100,:).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what `CPMD_PCA` is doing so I'll show you how to plot a moving windows on a simple matlab plot, on a sample data set.

You'll have to adjust the code to your exact application.

```
%% // just to create a sample set
x = ( 0:pi/10:150*pi ).' ; %//'
y = cos(x).*cos(3*x)+cos(x./4) ;
xdata = [y , -y/2] ;

%% // adjust moving window size and compute other useful parameters
window_size = 100 ;                 %// the length (in points) of the moving window
nPts = size(y,1) ;                  %// number of points in a column
n_windows = nPts-window_size ;      %// the total number of windows

%% // Do the initial plot (not moving yet) of the first 100 points
idx = 1:window_size ;
hp = plot( xdata( idx , 1) ) ;

%% // Move the plot by one point at each iteration of the loop
for iwin =1:n_windows
    idx = idx + 1 ;
    set( hp , 'YData' , xdata(idx,1) )
    drawnow                         %// you can comment that line (try with and without)
    pause(0.1)                      %// adjust the timing to your needs
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question directly you can wrap your current code in another loop:

```
for outer_loop_index = 1 : (size(xdata1,1) - 100)
    for inner_loop_index = outer_loop_index : outer_loop_index + 99
        NOC1 = CPMD_PCA(xdata1(inner_loop_index,:); 
    end
end
```